# Php switch to interface

Tags: php, forms, interface, switch-statement, polymorphism

Is there any way to replace this switch cases with Polymorphism(Interface)?
I got a form that has different fields, depending on product type it passes data into db.

```
public function typeHandler(){ 
switch($this->type){
  case 'unknown':
    return '';
  case 'dvd':
    $dvd = new Dvd($_POST);
    $product = new Product($_POST);
    $sa = $dvd->getSize();
    $product->setSa($sa);
    $product->save();
    $dvd->save();
    break;
  case 'book':
    $book = new Book($_POST);
    $product = new Product($_POST);
    $sa = $book->getWeight();
    $product->setSa($sa);
    $product->save();
    $book->save();
    break;
  case 'furniture':
    $furniture = new Furniture($_POST);
    $product = new Product($_POST);
    $sa = $furniture->getDimensions();
    $product->setSa($sa);
    $product->save();
    $furniture->save();
    break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following (one way to do it):

```php
interface Item {
   // This method will replace Dvd::getSize(), Book::getWeight() and Furniture::getDimensions().
   public function getSa();
   public function save();
}

class Dvd implements Item {
   ...
}

class Book implements Item {
   ...
}

class Furniture implements Item {
   ...
}

class ItemFactory {
    private $types = [
        'dvd' => Dvd::class,
        'book' => Book::class,
        'furniture' => Furniture::class,
    ];

    public function create($type, $constructData) {
        if (array_key_exists($type, $this->types)) {
            return new $this->types[$type]($constructData);
        }
        throw new Exception('No such type!');
    }
}

...

public function typeHandler() { 
    $item = (new ItemFactory)->create($this->type, $_POST);
    $product = new Product($_POST);
    $product->setSa($item->getSa());
    $product->save();
    $item->save();
}
```

**Note:** Not sure why the separate `Product` class, that could be entirely merged with the `Item` interface, depending on the details.

Comment: Thank you Zoli :)

Comment: @Remy Thanks for fixing the typo.